# What is the latest JDK version supported by Netbeans 8.2 (RCP)?

Tags: java, netbeans-8, java-9, netbeans-platform

So far I haven't found any mention about netbeans 8.2 supporting any later jdk version other than jdk8. Here my purpose is to integrate openjdk10 in a netbeans 8.2 RCP application.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. See if this link https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-3413139-esa.html could help.

Comment: Why not upgrade to NetBeans 9 (supports Java 9 and 10) or NetBeans 10 (supports Java 11)? You can find downloads and other information at https://netbeans.apache.org/.

Comment: The download documentation for NetBeans 8.2 explicitly states: [**JDK 8 is required for installing and running the Java SE, Java EE and All NetBeans Bundles. NetBeans 8.2 does not run on JDK 9 or later**](https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.2/). Don't waste your time trying to use any JDK > 8 with NetBeans 8.2 because it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK 8 - from the comment by @skomisa